# Tabs in Actionbarsherlock are always inside the actionbar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I was running the demo from Actionbersherlock samples and noticed the tabs were always inside the actionbar as in the picture. How do I fix this?
thnx.

[image]

```
public class TabNavigation extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private TextView mSelected;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
    mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText("Tab " + i);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    mSelected.setText("Selected: " + tab.getText());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
}
```

}

Code From here:

```
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java
```

Comment: what is your code for setting the actionbar mode, what sherlock style are you using for the app.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I added the code. actually I just executed the ABS demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Action Bar Tabs guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs):

> the system adapts the action bar tabs for different screen sizes—placing them in the main action bar when the screen is sufficiently wide, or in a separate bar (known as the "stacked action bar") when the screen is too narrow

As ActionBarSherlock mimics the platform behavior, tabs will appear in the Action Bar if there is enough space. You cannot force the stacked action bar pattern as per [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459902/force-stacked-tabs) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066589/how-to-force-splitting-actionbars-tab-and-title-home-menu).

Comment: I thought stacked bar is activated in portrait mode!

Comment: @ZahidHasan - it is based on available space, not any specific orientation. As there's no menu items added to the `ActionBar`, the entire remaining width could in theory be used for tabs. Something as simple as longer tab name lengths or the addition of a menu item may be enough to push it to a stacked action bar. The important part is that your application cannot (and should not) rely on one situation or the other.

Answer (score 1):

actionbarsherlock has different modes use the correct one

I use this:

`getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

and the tabs are below the bar.
the different modes should be listed in the samples and documentation