# Action Bar Spliting is not Working

Tags: android

I m using action bar in my app. but When i run the app on mobile action bar is splitting and show at the buttom. but When i run the app into sumsung tab split is not showing to me at buttom. Can any on tell me the reason thanks in advance. i m attaching the both screen shot. [image: mobile image]

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
            tab.setText("abc");
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_go);
            tab.setTabListener(new TabListener() {...}
    .....


    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.demoactionbar.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/group_item1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/group_item2"        
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="@string/group_item2"        
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

[image: Tab Image]

Comment: I think it splits the actionbar only if there is not enough room. In case of the tablet there is enough room for that

Answer (score 1):

I think it splits the actionbar only if there is not enough room. In case of the tablet there is enough room for that. You can't force split it. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066589/how-to-force-splitting-actionbars-tab-and-title-home-menu)

Comment: I have added 8 menu item. it shows 5 menu item at the top and rest of 3 menu item in list at buttom.

Comment: @UmeshKumarSaraswat because there is no more space for the 3

Comment: you are saying that there is no space for 3 menu item. but rest of 5 menu item should be displayed at the buttom.? but those 5 menu item are showing at topp?

Comment: @UmeshKumarSaraswat Well I'm saying that the menu items are added to the actionbar only if there is enough space. Otherwise they will be split and added to button (if you have `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` for your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`).